# assets problem Symfony from root directory

Tags: webpack, symfony4, assets

My problem is simple but can't find a solution yet.

When my assets are loaded, it does look in my root directory rather than in my public directory.

Nevertheless, I did "php bin/console assets:install public".

I generate my assets using webpack encore also on SYMFONY 4 :

./node_modules/.bin/encore dev

But, I get a 404 for all my assets located in public because it does search for it in root directory.

If someone encounter this kind of classic problem, any help would be lovely.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem is related to subdomains.

You need to precise in the documentation the path related to assets in case your using folder as subdomain.

I found some documentation about it here :

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets